# Logic App retrieve values from custom created parameter names in a text file

Tags: mapping, azure-logic-apps, file-storage

having trouble with Logic App usage, so i am receiving a file with example text below and need to map them according to their tags. so for each tag they will go to different fields in my database. Keep in mind I **cannot** change the structure of the file, stays as is due to previous systems:

:2e:hello
:3t:there
:fy:people

What I do is pull the file from file storage and them i can access the content which are the values above. But what I need to do is check if i have ':2e:' and if so take its value which is 'there'.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: do a plit on `space` character you will have all the key value pairs then do a split on `:` you will be able to get individual values ????

Comment: split on space will not be the solution here, there are 2 colons remember, so from your solution this is what will happen:

spacing split:
:2e:hello
:3e:there
:fy: people

split colon
:2e
:hello
:3t
:there

etc

Comment: if you split on space you will have `:2e:hello` `:3t:there` `:fy:people`. Remove the first colon/character then you will have `2e:hello` `3t:there` `fy:people` Then you split on colon, you will have `2e and `hello`. Just check if you have `2e` and you will find easily the corresponding value `hello`

Comment: So then it becomes
2e
hello
3t
there